# Hide table content if value is null in PDFMake

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, pdfmake

I want to hide a table content if a certain variable is null.

The table design code :

```
{
          color: '#000000',
          margin: [25, 10, 0, 0],
          table: {
            body: [
              [
                {
                  text: 'STRUCTURAL/FOUNDATION',
                  alignment: 'center',
                  style: 'subheader',
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
          layout: {
            hLineColor: function (i, node) {
              return 'black';
            },
            vLineColor: function (i, node) {
              return 'black';
            },
            paddingLeft: function (i, node) {
              return 100;
            },
            paddingRight: function (i, node) {
              return 100;
            },
            paddingTop: function (i, node) {
              return 2;
            },
            paddingBottom: function (i, node) {
              return 2;
            },
          },
        },
```

If `this.StoredData.structureDescription` is null, then this above code should be hidden (i.e, nothing to be displayed on the pdf).

Comment: Unless you have code/template infrastructure specific to this problem in reactjs, angularjs, or ionic-framework to share, you should probably remove those tags.

Comment: changed it. I'm using ionic-framework for angularjs